# Getting specific number of OMDB movie results

Tags: json, swift, url

My `swift` app allows one to search for a movie thanks to the OMDB database. I'm trying to figure out how to return more than 10 results per search though. searchKeyword is the string value that the user is entering to search for the movie. I am using swiftyJSON to extract the Json data.

```
. . .
//store search url
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "https://www.omdbapi.com/")!
urlComponents.query = "s=\"\(searchKeyword)\""
let url = urlComponents.URL!
//extract json
let json = getJSON(url.absoluteString)

//How do I ensure that 50 items are downloaded here?
if let items = json["Search"].array {
    for item in items {
        ...
        extract data needed from item
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Rashwan L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5576310/rashwan-l) already metioned the API has currently no support to get more than 10 results per request.
But you can send multiple requests and utilize their pagination parameter **page** to get up to 1000 results, see their API parameters [here](http://www.omdbapi.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This has to be a parameter in your URL, but OMDB does not have any support for that. Check their API-list [here](https://www.omdbapi.com).